# Google Appengine: admin access

Tags: google-app-engine, permissions, admin

We are using Google AppEngine for my site. Unfortunately I can't seem to get full owner admin access even though I am supposed to be a Super Admin according to my Google account.

When I go to Google Appengine (https://appengine.google.com/permissions....) using my Google account, it indicates I am a "developer". I believe I need full owner access in order to upload ssl certificate for the domain plus add or edit the permission. I've called Google support and they wash their hands saying the above is outside their core knowledge. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps admin status does not give you "owner" status on AppEngine. Owner of the AppEngine app has to go to the "Permissions" tab in GAE console and grant you this status.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I am the owner of the AppEngine app but from the GAE permissions link (https://appengine.google.com/permissions...) I see my name and it indicates I'm a developer not the owner so I can't change the permissions.

Comment: No. Only me. My programmer has access to the appengine but only as a developer.

Comment: Huh, no owners? That sounds like a bug. You should report it here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list